# How do I check if my int array is empty, with the standard value being 0?

Tags: java, arrays, null, integer, zero

So I have come across an issue I do not seem to be able to fix. So lets say I have an int array and want to check whether the array still has space to add a certain element (from 0-∞) or has no space left, which would mean I would need to create a new array.

The issue is that when my int array has a space to store ten values, all of the spaces are filled with 0, so my program thinks that this array is full. And I can not exclude 0 either because the element which I want to add could be 0 aswell.

Any advice?

Comment: Have a counter.  Special values are a bad idea.

Comment: An [IntBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/IntBuffer.html) is almost certainly what you want.  For example, `IntBuffer values = IntBuffer.allocate(10);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using an `int[]`? The primitive type `int` can not be `null`. A very simple solution would be to use the wrapper class `Integer`.

```
Integer[] intArray = {null, 0, 10};
```

Comment: Interesting solution! Nice.

Comment: At the expense of memory.

Comment: But maybe ,as mentioned in another answer, a `List` is a better solution for you.

Comment: Thanks! Thats the simple solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of which positions are filled via additional variables. A Java array itself (when created) is initialized with 0-s and it is technically always full.

If you need a dynamically expanding array, my suggestion is to use `java.util.List`, which is very handy and in most situations can replace a Java array nicely.

A List tutorial is easy to find, here is [an example](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-list) .

And this is how you use it:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

....
List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add("Hello");
a.add("World");
System.out.println(a.size());
```

You can easily convert to a standard array: `a.toArray()`.

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers are always greater or equal 0, you could just set unused numbers to -1.